# rails member routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'm creating a route that should have a url of something like `http://mysite/cars/1/similar/`, which would get all cars similar to a car with the specified id (in this case 1)

I've seen that you can create rails member routes in the routes.rb file with the syntax

```
resources :cars do
  member do
    get :similar
  end
end
```

I can also do something like

```
match 'cars/:id/similar' => 'cars#similar', :via => "get
```

What is the difference between these two syntaxes

Comment: If you're not declaring multiple member resources, I find it cleaner to do `get :similar, on: :member` or even `member { get :similar }`

Comment: And also `get "cars/:id/similar" => "cars#similar"` instead of `match... :via => "get"` while you're at it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One is unified within default resource route declarations, IMO easier to find. The other isn't, which could lead to typos etc. Not a *huge* deal, but for RESTful actions, I'd rather use the resourceful mechanism.

You can also use the single-line version, which I prefer for single routes:

```
resources :cars do
  get :similar, :on => :member
end
```

Meagar is correct, I forgot that the match form will not create the helper methods.

Comment: Just to add that if you have multiple members within the resource it would be easier to just add the verb and action name to the block rather than explicitly writing out the whole individual 'match' route.

Comment: @JeffStorey No, it's not the same.

Answer (score 8):

The two methods are not equivalent.

The first method produces a `similar_car` helper method. The second method does not.

The helper method is important if you intend to do things like

```
= link_to "Similar", similar_car_path(@car)
```

In order to make them equivalent, you would have to provide an `:as` option:

```
get "cars/:id/similar" => "cars#similar", :as => "similar_car"
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize the first way automatically created the helpers.